# flv to mp4 using ffmpeg cli on debian

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, command-line-interface, flv

I'm trying to convert [this flv file](http://storage.googleapis.com/tpc-ms-photos-1/videoStream_1424268207948_854.flv) into .mp4 using ffmpeg on debian.

- Stream 0 Type: Video Codec: Flash Video (FLV1) Resolution: 640x480
  Frame rate: 1000 Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

  Stream 1 Type: Audio Codec: NellyMoser ASAO (NELL) Channels: Mono
  Sample rate: 22050 Hz Bits per sample: 32

I'm currently using this simple command...

***sudo avconv -i videoStream_1424268207948_854.flv videoStream_1424268207948_854.mp4***

These are the warnings I receive:

- [flv @ 0x14fab20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
- [libx264 @ 0x14fdaa0] MB rate (1200000) > level limit (983040)
- Multiple frames in a packet from stream 0
- [flv @ 0x14fca60] Bad picture start code
- [flv @ 0x14fca60] header damaged
- Error while decoding stream #0:0

... and it [results](http://storage.googleapis.com/tpc-ms-photos-1/videoStream_1424268207948_854.mp4) in messed up video and audio.

Can anyone help with some parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me using ffmpeg version 2.5.4. Try upgrading avconv, or switching to ffmpeg.